# Hybrid Search: missing results

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, hybrid-solution

We are using SharePoint 2013 On Premises and SharePoint Online (Office 365). We are using the Cloud Search Service to provide Hybrid Search functionality.

We have added SharePoint online as a result source ('HybridResults') in the On Premise Search Service Application

We are observing the following behavior:

1. when adding a Content Search Webpart (CSWP) on a page in SharePoint Online and specifying the following query we are receiving all expected results: `contentclass:STS_Web path:https://ourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/departments`
2. when adding a CSWP on a page in SharePoint Premise and selecting the 'HybridResults' resultsource and specifying the exact same query we are receiving just 1 resultitem.

I've exported the CSWP and changed TrimDuplicates to False under DataProviderJSON

What more can I do to receive all results?

Update:

I've also tried the following queries using the API, which suggest the issue is related to TrimDuplicates:

1. `/_api/search/query?querytext='b-nl'&querytemplate='path:https://ourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/departments contentclass:sts_web'` contains 1 result:

> ```
> <d:TotalRows m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:TotalRows>
> <d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates m:type="Edm.Int32">223</d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates>
> ```

2. `/_api/search/query?querytext='b-nl'&querytemplate='path:https://ourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/departments contentclass:sts_web'&trimduplicates=false` contains all results:

> ```
> <d:TotalRows m:type="Edm.Int32">223</d:TotalRows>
> <d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates m:type="Edm.Int32">223</d:TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates>
> ```

Comment: Are you certain the problem is duplicates? It could be that the On-Prem identity is not being correctly recognized by Office 365. Do you have the prerequisite User Synchronization and User Profile Service configured?

Comment: I'm pretty sure: I can find every single site that I want by changing my query, I just can't receive more than one result at a time. It's not like some results are inaccessible, they are just missing from certain query's.

Comment: and, yes, Active Directory synchronization with Azure Active Directory is configured and working fine

Comment: Did you find any solution? I gues this is still a problem. SharePoint 2016 OnPRemise is still just returning the trimmed results from O365. This article talks about the same problem. http://summit7systems.com/beware-of-duplicates-in-sharepoint-onlines-content-search-web-part/

Comment: unfortunately not, we decided to work around it by redirecting users to equivalent pages in SharePoint Online that work as expected

Comment: it would be nice to try the workaround in the article, though, just to see if that works